# JAVA NIO TCP how to read first packet and authenticate

Tags: java, nio

I am writing a server socket which listens and authenticates the gps packet. Whenever the first packet arrives I need to authenticate the IMEI number sent which is the first packet. SO, how can I check first packet of data and if it is valid then need to send the 1 byte data as 0x01. After accepting the data(0x01) acceptance data device sends telemetry data. So, foreach data then I need to reply with length of the packet.

So, how can I check the first packet and then after replying I need to allow for device to send data and read it.

**Below is the sample code:**

```
public class CustomSocketChannelHandler<E extends Event<SocketChannel>> extends SocketChannelHandler<E> {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream currBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);

    private byte[] inMsgDemarcatorBytes;
    private boolean keepInMsgDemarcator;
    private int currDelimeterByteIndex;

    public CustomSocketChannelHandler(final SelectionKey key,
                                        final AsyncChannelDispatcher dispatcher,
                                        final Charset charset,
                                        final EventFactory<E> eventFactory,
                                        final BlockingQueue<E> events,
                                        final ComponentLog logger,
                                        final byte[] inMsgDemarcatorBytes,
                                        final boolean keepInMsgDemarcator) {
        super(key, dispatcher, charset, eventFactory, events, logger);
        this.inMsgDemarcatorBytes = inMsgDemarcatorBytes;
        this.keepInMsgDemarcator = keepInMsgDemarcator;
        this.currDelimeterByteIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean eof = false;
        SocketChannel socketChannel = null;

        try {
            int bytesRead;
            socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

            final SocketChannelAttachment attachment = (SocketChannelAttachment) key.attachment();
            final ByteBuffer socketBuffer = attachment.getByteBuffer();

            // read until the buffer is full
            while ((bytesRead = socketChannel.read(socketBuffer)) > 0) {
                // prepare byte buffer for reading
                socketBuffer.flip();
                // mark the current position as start, in case of partial message read
                socketBuffer.mark();
                // process the contents that have been read into the buffer
                processBuffer(socketChannel, socketBuffer);

                // Preserve bytes in buffer for next call to run
                // NOTE: This code could benefit from the  two ByteBuffer read calls to avoid
                // this compact for higher throughput
                socketBuffer.reset();
                socketBuffer.compact();
                logger.info("bytes read {}", new Object[]{bytesRead});
            }

            // Check for closed socket
            if( bytesRead < 0 ){
                eof = true;
                logger.info("Reached EOF, closing connection");
            } else {
                logger.info("No more data available, returning for selection");
            }
        } catch (ClosedByInterruptException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("read loop interrupted, closing connection");
            // Treat same as closed socket
            eof = true;
        } catch (ClosedChannelException e) {
            // ClosedChannelException doesn't have a message so handle it separately from IOException
            logger.error("Error reading from channel due to channel being closed", e);
            // Treat same as closed socket
            eof = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error reading from channel due to {}", new Object[] {e.getMessage()}, e);
            // Treat same as closed socket
            eof = true;
        } finally {
            if(eof == true) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(socketChannel);
                dispatcher.completeConnection(key);
            } else {
                dispatcher.addBackForSelection(key);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process the contents that have been read into the buffer. Allow sub-classes to override this behavior.
     *
     * @param socketChannel the channel the data was read from
     * @param socketBuffer the buffer the data was read into
     * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted when queuing events
     */
    protected void processBuffer(final SocketChannel socketChannel, final ByteBuffer socketBuffer) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        // get total bytes in buffer
        final int total = socketBuffer.remaining();
        final InetAddress sender = socketChannel.socket().getInetAddress();

        // go through the buffer looking for the end of each message
        currBytes.reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            // NOTE: For higher throughput, the looking for \n and copying into the byte stream could be improved
            // Pull data out of buffer and cram into byte array
            byte currByte = socketBuffer.get();

            // check if at end of a message
            if (currByte == inMsgDemarcatorBytes[currDelimeterByteIndex]) {

                if(keepInMsgDemarcator) {
                    currBytes.write(currByte);
                }

                // If the last byte in inMsgDemarcatorBytes is reached, then separate message
                if (currDelimeterByteIndex == inMsgDemarcatorBytes.length - 1) {
                    if (currBytes.size() > 0) {
                        final SocketChannelResponder response = new SocketChannelResponder(socketChannel);
                        final Map<String, String> metadata = EventFactoryUtil.createMapWithSender(sender.toString());
                        final E event = eventFactory.create(currBytes.toByteArray(), metadata, response);
                        events.offer(event);
                        currBytes.reset();

                        // Reset the currDelimeterByteIndex to 0 to start the next detection
                        currDelimeterByteIndex = 0;

                        // Mark this as the start of the next message
                        socketBuffer.mark();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Don't write the delimeter bytes to output
                    currDelimeterByteIndex++;
                }
            } else {
                currBytes.write(currByte);
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte getDelimiter() {
        return '\n';
    }

}
```

reference link for code:
https://github.com/linksmart/nifi-customlistentcp-processor

Comment: You could use a hashset in order to check which devices are already authenticated (after the first packet is correctly read). If the device isn't inside the set, then you must check the IMEI, since it's the first message sent from that device. Also, you should manage the disconnections, in order to delete the non-working devices from the set. Rethink the idea of sending the authentication key via TCP without security (i guess isn't a secured connection as you implemented an authentication method)

Comment: @aran thanks for the response, but how to read first packet? and also as the device is sending in this I need to integrate in this way only.

Comment: Do you mean you can't identify the first packet, or that you can't start reading any message from the socket?

Comment: I didn't get how to read/ identify first packet.

Comment: Check first wether any message is being sent. You could use netstat or similar tools to do so; If the messages are correctly being sent, debug your listener and check if the connection is succesfull

Comment: Also, may this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16592107/2148953