# UDP Socket Bind Any IP? (Wildcard - Particular)

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, ip, bind

I'm working on a socket project and now I'll make a UDP listener for server-side. I have looked some examples and I can't understand this; Why we have to bind UDP socket like "socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(**IPAddress.Any**, 3000));"? Namely: in the TCP socket, we bind only our local ip but in UDP socket, we are binding IPAddress.Any. Why we are doing this?

EDIT: What are the wildcard and particular IP Adresses? How can we use them?

Comment: I think this [article](http://bert-hubert.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/on-binding-datagram-udp-sockets-to-any.html) could clarify the ANY for UDP.

Comment: 'In the TCP socket we bind only [to] our local IP' isn't correct. You usually bind a listening socket to ANY as well. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP OK. I need to understand why we need to user ANY Ip or special Ip. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this and I think I was looking for it :)

> The wildcard is a special local IP address. It usually means "any" and
>   can only be used for bind operations.
>
> The value of this IP address is 0.0.0.0. If you have two network
>   adapters, one with IP address 1.1.1.1 and one with IP address 2.2.2.2,
>   then you can create a listening socket and bind it to 1.1.1.1 so that
>   the socket will not bind to 2.2.2.2. You can also create a listening
>   socket and bind it to 2.2.2.2, so that it will not bind to 1.1.1.1. If
>   you do not care and want your socket to bind to all network cards,
>   then you bind it to the wildcard address.
>
> Another special value would be 127.0.0.1, meaning that only clients on
>   the same computer could connect to your server.

Link: [What does wildcard address in InetSocketAddress mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931175/what-does-wildcard-address-in-inetsocketaddress-mean)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind both TCP and UDP sockets to either the wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY` or `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`) or to a specific address. There is no reason why you would typically bind a TCP socket to a specific IP address while you would bind a UDP socket to a wildcard address.

Comment: Of course there are reasons why you would want to bind to a wildcard address vs. a particular address, but they have nothing to do with whether you're using TCP or UDP. It's really orthogonal...

Comment: OK. Can you tell me? Why I need to use wildcard and why I need to use particular address?

Comment: Well, you would bind to a wildcard address if you want to receive packets sent to any of the IP addresses on the local system (including loopbacks `127.0.0.1` and `::1`). You would bind to a specific address if you only want to receive packets sent to that address. This is valid for both TCP and UDP (except that working with UDP sockets which are bound to wildcard and which both send and receive can be tricky).

Comment: hmm, but "local". If I sent data from an other city (over InterNetwork) what should I bind?

Comment: I want to send data from an other city (not local). What I need to do?

Comment: I fail to understand why we are talking about cities.

Comment: The most common reason for specifying a bind address is if you have a machine with multiple network interfaces (say, two Ethernet cards) and you want to explicitly specify which interface to listen on, as opposed to hoping that the default one is the one that you are concerned with. In most situations you specify INADDR_ANY.